# Recursive Mine Explosion Function On a Board Game

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to implement a board game on C++ and its some features are below:

- I have 4 sources named as Mine (M), Water (W), Food (F) and Medical Supplies (S)
- The Sources will be distributed to the board randomly (which I completed)
- User will enter two coordinates and if there is mine on these coordinates they will just blow up and destroy the cells around them depending on their place. For example if the mine is on somewhere in the middle it will destroy the 8 cells around it and if there is another mine around the one which is exploded it will make the other one explode, too.
- And there are some exceptions for example if the coordinate is on the corner it will just blow up 3 cell around it.

Let's come to the real problem. When I try to implement it I saw that it is tons of codes actually and I need to make it recursive to give the ability to blow up other cells so for every single possilibility I need to check if the blown cell is a mine or not. Is there an efficient way to implement this or do I need to just write the whole code?

```
    void explode_mines(int x,int y) {
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            grid[0][0] = 'X';
            grid[0][1] = 'X';
            if (grid[0][1] == 'X') explode_mines(0, 1);
            grid[1][0] = 'X';
            //...
            grid[1][1] = 'X';
            //...
    }
    //Is there any efficient way?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
void ExploreCell(int x, int y)
{
    if (x or y are out of bounds (less than zero/greater than max))
       or (this cell is a mountain, because mountains don't explode))
        return
    else if this location is a mine
        ExplodeMine(x, y) //This cell is a mine, so it blows up again
    else
        DestroyCell(x, y) //This cell is a valid, non-mine target
}

void ExplodeMine(int x, int y)
{
    ExploreCell(x-1, y-1);
    ExploreCell(x-1, y);
    ....
    ExploreCell(x+1, y+1);
}

void DestroyCell(int x, int y)
{
      //Take care of business
}
```

Comment: The first step of `explodeCell()` checks to see if the cell is real.  If it is not, for example if it is at (-1, 0), it doesn't do anything.  You can also add more checks.  I'll edit my example in a second.

Comment: @LogicStuff I wasn't spending too much time worrying about the specifics, more about the logic.  I'll make some edits though

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a typo in your code:

```
        grid[0][1] = 'X';
        if (grid[0][1] == 'X') explode_mines(0, 1);
```

How would location (0,1) *not* be 'X" at this point?

---

It doesn't *have* to be recursive, but information theory does say that you have to make 8 checks.  You *can* make it more readable, however.  For general purposes, I've found the basic perimeter check to be maintainable.  Here, I'll let "O" be a crater and ""M" be a mine.

```
grid[x][y] = ' '
for (row = x-1; row <= x+1; row++) {
    for (col = x-1; col <= x+1; col++) {
        if grid[row][col] == "M"
            explode_mines(row, col)
    }
}
```

Now, *if* you have to worry about the time spent for a huge chain reaction, then you can alter your algorithm to keep two lists:

- Squares that need checking
- Squares with mines to blow up

In this case, **explode_mines** looks more like this:

```
Mark x,y as a dead square
Add adjacent squares to the checking list; do *not* add a duplicate
```

... and you get a new routine **check_for_mine** that looks like this:

```
while check list is not empty {
  while mine list is not empty {
    explode the top mine on the list
  }
  take the top square from the check list and check it
}
```

You can play with the nesting, depending on what chain-reaction order you'd like.  For breadth-first explosions, you check all squares on the check list, then explode all the mines on the mine list; repeat that until both lists are empty.  For depth-first, you can simplify the loops a little: explode every mine as soon as you find it, which means that you don't need a mine list at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this helps [caution: not tested] ('d' for "destroied", 'b' for "bomb")

```
void destroy (int x, int y)
 {
   char  oldVal;

   if (    (x >= 0) && (x < maxX) && (y >= 0) && (y < maxY)
        && ('d' != (oldVal = grid[x][y])) ) // 'd' for destroyed
    {
      grid[x][y] = 'd';  // set "destroyed"

      if ( 'b' == oldVal ) // if it was a bomb, destroy surrounding
       {
         destroy(x-1, y-1);
         destroy(x-1, y);
         destroy(x-1, y+1);
         destroy(x,   y-1);
         destroy(x,   y+1);
         destroy(x+1, y-1);
         destroy(x+1, y);
         destroy(x+1, y+1);
       }
    }
 }
```